# Deployment of TeamCity to a Azure web site fails

Tags: tomcat, teamcity

I'm trying to get [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) working on a [Azure web site](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/web-sites/).

I start out with a Tomcat 7 container template and then I simply ftp the TeamCity-8.1.1.war into the webapps folder in Tomcat (after renaming it to TeamCity.war).

When I browse to the site I get the following message:

[image: Unable to initialize logs. The logs directories are not accessible for writing.]

Text version:

## TeamCity has failed to start

Unable to initialize logs. The logs directories are not accessible for writing.

TeamCity server process does not have enough permissions to write into the log files under the directory:

`D:\Windows\Logs`

Please fix permissions and restart TeamCity. You can read more about TeamCity logs in documentation.

---

According to the [TeamCity documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/TeamCity+Server+Logs) the place where TeamCity normally saves logs is `<TeamCity Server home>\logs`. However why TeamCity wants to write to `D:\Windows\Logs` I don't understand.

How can I set up TeamCity to work on a Azure web site?

Comment: Sounds to me like your missing some config files on your azure deployment

Comment: This question has no relevance to Azure, it's really a TeamCity setup issue.

Comment: @James using a java container on Azure websites may be problem free, but why are you so certain? (it may help me debugging to know why.)

Comment: Do you use .war TeamCity distribution?

Comment: Why use Azure WebSites rather than an Azure VM? I would expect that you will have many problems with TeamCity within Websites, and this is just the first of many: Disk space quota, CPU time quota, and so on.

Comment: @JayHarris Azure websites is a cheaper solution. I plan to have only the server part of Teamcity on the website. So not build agents nor database, so I don't think there should not be any of the problems you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Teamcity server requires permissions that are not available to azure web site (to open ports, run executable and initiate external connections) on the other hand Teamcity server is where artifacts(binary files from build) are stored that requires a lot of storage.

Running TC server inside a azure website is not possible, You need a VM to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I got a confirmation for the JetBrains staff that **it is impossible** to run TeamCity server on Azure Websites.

See [this discussion on JetBrains Developer Community](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5536564):

> TC Server indeed requires additional permissions, such as creating directories, open connections, etc.